# Current location using wi-fi on BlackBerry Storm 2 (9550)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, location-provider

I want to get the current location using wi-fi on my Storm 2 9550. I have implemented [LocationProvider](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/javax/microedition/location/LocationProvider.html) and it is working fine on the simulator after sending lat long manually, but it doesn't work on the device.

GPS is already active on the device but to my knowledge BlackBerry GPS cannot get location without a Network Provider.  There is no network provider on the device.

Comment: LocationProvider can get GPS fixes without being on a network. GPS chips need some time to get "hot" and find sats, expect about a minute or so to get a fix. You'll need to be outdoors for it to work.

Comment: without Network, it should be work or not ?

Comment: It depends on the mode used. Regular GPS mode should work in GPS-enabled devices like 9550. But geolocation using Cell data won't work unless you are on a carrier network, and WiFi geolocation won't work unless you have WiFi enabled and there are APs available.

Comment: BTW, WiFi geolocation was addded in OS 6.0. Have a look at dev. guide: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/36458/index.jsp?name=Location-Based+Services+-+Development+Guide+-+BlackBerry+Java+SDK7.1+Beta&language=English&userType=21&category=Java+Development+Guides+and+API+Reference&subCategory=