# How to get geolocation without GPS on Blackberry OS 5

Tags: blackberry, java-me, gps

I've got geolocation from GPS for OS 5 and above.

I need to get geolocation from the network. If GPS is disabled, I need to collect the geolocation information from the network for OS 5.

I've checked [this BlackBerry document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/34488/Geolocation_overview_1679739_11.jsp).

They give a solution for  OS 6 and above.

Can we get geolocation without GPS for blackberry OS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
try {

    int cellID = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getCellId();
    int lac = GPRSInfo.getCellInfo().getLAC();

    String urlString2 = "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap";
    if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
            && RadioInfo
                    .areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
        urlString2 += ";interface=wifi;ConnectionTimeout=60000";
    }else  if (TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B) && TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B)) {
        System.out.println("BIS CONNECTION-------------------");
        // Holder.connectionInterface=";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";
        urlString2 += ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public;ConnectionTimeout=60000";
    } 


    // Open a connection to Google Maps API 
    ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
    ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
    connDesc = connFact.getConnection(urlString2);

    HttpConnection httpConn2;
    httpConn2 = (HttpConnection)connDesc.getConnection();
    httpConn2.setRequestMethod("POST");

    // Write some custom data to Google Maps API 
    OutputStream outputStream2 = httpConn2.openOutputStream();//getOutputStream();
    WriteDataGoogleMaps(outputStream2, cellID, lac);

    // Get the response  
    InputStream inputStream2 = httpConn2.openInputStream();//getInputStream();
    DataInputStream dataInputStream2 = new DataInputStream(inputStream2);

    // Interpret the response obtained 
    dataInputStream2.readShort();
    dataInputStream2.readByte();

    int code = dataInputStream2.readInt();
    //Dialog.alert(code+"");

    if (code == 0) {
        latitude= dataInputStream2.readInt() / 1000000D;
        longitude=dataInputStream2.readInt() / 1000000D;

        //Dialog.alert(latitude+"-----"+longitude);  

        dataInputStream2.readInt();
        dataInputStream2.readInt();
        dataInputStream2.readUTF();

    } else {
        System.out.println("Error obtaining Cell Id ");
    }
    outputStream2.close();
    inputStream2.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**WriteDataGoogleMaps()**  method -

```
private static void WriteDataGoogleMaps(OutputStream out, int cellID, int lac)
throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
    dataOutputStream.writeShort(21);
    dataOutputStream.writeLong(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("en");
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Android");
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("1.0");
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("Web");
    dataOutputStream.writeByte(27);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(3);
    dataOutputStream.writeUTF("");
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(cellID);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(lac);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(0);
    dataOutputStream.flush();
}
```

Comment: hi.. in WriteDataGoogleMaps() method what we do?

Comment: hi signare, its working only on wifi network? i've checked to turn off the wifi, and connected 3g sim. Its not get the geo point..  what shall i change for that?

Comment: change the connection string and try

Comment: @Ganesh, I would recommend replacing the code above that uses connection strings with code that uses the `ConnectionFactory` APIs that were added in OS 5.0.  It makes it easier to select a number of network transports that you can use, for making your connection to the `http://www.google.com/glm/mmap` URL.

Comment: @Signare hi., i've wifi connection, and insert 3g sim card.  Its working to get location from sim card. If i disable mobile network . this code is not working. can we get location from wifi ?

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you, in addition to [@Signare's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17184111/119114), is to use the [Simple Location API](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Simple-Location-API/ta-p/1145951), which is available for OS 5.0 and greater.

[Download the source code from github](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Simple%20Location%20API) and include it in your project.

Then, to acquire location fixes without using the GPS, try this:

```java
 try {
    simpleProvider = new SimpleLocationProvider(SimpleLocationProvider.MODE_GEOLOCATION);
 } catch(LocationException le){ 
    // thrown if the selected mode (in this case MODE_GEOLOCATION) is not available.
 }
 BlackBerryLocation location = simpleProvider.getLocation(120); // 120 seconds timeout
```

You can also use the [SimpleLocationListener](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/blob/master/Simple%20Location%20API/src/rimx/location/simplelocation/SimpleLocationListener.java) interface if you wish to have your code called back with location data at a specified *interval*.

In OS 6.0, this API adds the ability to specifically select the cell network as a location provider, or use the Wi-Fi network.  In OS 5.0, you are limited to these three choices:

> **MODE_GEOLOCATION** - Operates strictly in Geolocation mode. 
>   **MODE_GPS** -
>   Operates strictly in GPS (aka Standalone/Autonomous) mode. 
>   **MODE_OPTIMAL** - Operates in both Geolocation and GPS mode based on
>   availability.

But, using `MODE_GEOLOCATION` or `MODE_OPTIMAL` will allow you to get location fixes without using the GPS chip.

Comment: hi. I've loaded the cod file on my device 9550. when we choose 'GEOLOATION' Its throw an exception. javax.microedition.locaion.LocaionEception:MODE_GEOLOCATION is not currently available on this device.

Comment: @Ganesh, Did you have mobile internet coverage (network available) when you tried this? Just to be clear, this mode uses `GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_CELLSITE`, which uses the GSM or CDMA cellular network. If your test device **only** has Wi-Fi connectivity, but not a valid carrier network, it won't work for you. Looking at your comments on the other answer, it looked like you were looking for a way to get location without Wi-Fi. With location services, especially on OS 5.0, it often requires a combination of techniques, which is why I added this second answer, in addition to Signare's.

Comment: Yes. My mobile has internet coverage. I've inserted 3g sim and also wifi is available.

Comment: @Ganesh, the Wi-Fi doesn't help you in this case.  Inserting a 3G SIM is good, but your mobile network must also be configured.  Can you access the internet normally over 3G if Wi-Fi is turned off?  Also, it's possible that your carrier is blocking this.  Which carrier are you using?  Are you on a normal **BlackBerry** plan with this carrier, or do you share this SIM card with other mobile devices (for example, an Android device that's your main phone)?

Comment: I've turned off wifi connection. i've checked 3g network. i've opend brower and check net is available or not. the 3g net is working.i dont know is it bis connection. I think its normal 3g net connection. I've changed the sim to android phone and check the net connection. Its also working on android phone too..

Comment: Hi., i've doubt, if we connect on bis only, we can get loation ?

Comment: @Ganesh, if you have a valid BlackBerry BIS plan from your carrier, then I think you should be able to get cell geolocation without Wi-Fi.  But, check [this BlackBerry document](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949), and look at the section titled **BlackBerry Geolocation Modes** for requirements for this to work.  For more information, see the [comments on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8291480/119114) from Mister Smith.